# How to calculate cost of an order on an online menu in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a v simple online menu for a takaway website - it is in an html table. I have a basic function that picks up the item's value, stored in one TD, then the quantity ordered, stored in another TD, and calculates the cost of the order accordingly. Only issue is I have hardcoded the id's of the 1st product and 1st product quantity into my function to get it to work for that item, but there is a list of about 20 items. Short of repeating my function 20 times, I cant work out how I can give the function the correct 2 ids for each item on the menu. The menu is here http://www.port80services.com/curry/menu.html

I am sure it should be relatively simple, but javascript just isnt my thing!

function:

```
function toPay(){

   var form = document.forms['form'];

   var itemcost = document.getElementById('meat_samosa_price').innerHTML;

   var qty = form.meat_samosa_qty.value;

      var res = Math.abs(itemcost  * qty);

    document.getElementById('order-total').innerHTML = "order total = €"+ res;

}
```

Comment: One approach, if you're just using basic javascript is to give each price and qty element the same name. You can then access all of them by doing getElementsByName() and then use the array in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

`var itemcost = document.getElementById('meat_samosa_price').innerHTML;` is a string, you cannot perform math of this data until you convert it to a number:

```
var itemcost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('meat_samosa_price').innerHTML);
```